# Regex match overlap/crossover

Tags: php, regex

I need to capitalise acronyms in some text.

I currently have this regex to match on the acronyms:

```
/(^|[^a-z0-9])(ECU|HVAC|ABS|ESC|EGR|ADAS|HEV|HMI)($|[^a-z0-9])/ig
```

Explanation: this is aiming to match any of the acronyms where they are either at the start or end of the text, or there isn't a letter or number either side of them (as then they might be part of a word - e.g. I wouldn't want to replace the "Esc" in the word "Escape").

This works most of the time, but doesn't work for the following example:

```
"abs/esc"
```

It matches the `abs`, but not the `esc`. I'm guessing this is because the matches overlap, in that the forward slash is part of the match relating to `abs`.

Can anyone suggest how to get a match on both?

As a side note, I'm using PHPs preg_replace_callback to perform the transformation afterwards:

```
$name = 'abs/esc';
$name = preg_replace_callback('/(^|[^a-z0-9])('ECU|HVAC|ABS|ESC|EGR|ADAS|HEV|HMI')($|[^a-z0-9])/i', function($matches) {
    return $matches[1] . strtoupper($matches[2]) . $matches[3];
}, $name);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the reason is because it overlaps (when matching the `abs`, it also consumes the `/`. Then for `esc`, it cannot find `[^a-z0-9]` because the next letter it is scanning is `e`).

You could use this RegEx instead:

```
\b(ECU|HVAC|ABS|ESC|EGR|ADAS|HEV|HMI)\b
```

`\b` is a [**Word Boundary**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), it does not consume any characters and therefore there will be no overlap

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/uZ7vS9/1)</kbd>

---

You can also change your RegEx to use a **Positive Lookahead**, since this also does not consume characters:

```
(^|[^a-z0-9])(ECU|HVAC|ABS|ESC|EGR|ADAS|HEV|HMI)(?=$|[^a-z0-9])
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/tT2aF2/1)</kbd>

Comment: Arg - forgot about word boundary - a rookie error - thanks.

Comment: Yep - just waiting for it to allow me to - seems to be a delay on it

Comment: No problem! And, yes, there is a delay (I find it annoying too). Thanks! :)