# Regular how to match two words near each other with shared letter in the middle

Tags: php, regex

For example, I have a string "xxxABCDExxx", and I have two keywords "ABC" and "CDE", now I want get "ABC" and "CDE" from string.

In php, `preg_match_all('/(ABC|CDE)/'..` will only match ABC or CDE, but not both.

Is there any way to match keywords even they're adjacent and share the same word.

Comment: What environment and tools are you using?  Not all flavors of regex are created equal.

Comment: @Gary_W I used PHP language.

Comment: Please re-read you question, and use the [edit] feature of SO, to correct "DEF"...

Comment: Please use [edit] feature of SO to add the tag `php` ... 

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36787495/regex-match-overlap-crossover

Comment: @LucasMendonça No, it's not, because `/b` or `Positive Lookahead` divide them with different things like `not a-z0-9`.

Comment: @Pader Afaik [capturing inside a lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11430863/5527985) is only way for overlapping matches: [`(?=(ABC|CDE))`](https://regex101.com/r/ZY7XYL/1)

Comment: https://3v4l.org/C2jEP

Comment: @bobblebubble Sorry for the later comment, that is what I want, thank you.